# Action Filter Attribute does not work correctly with Hub class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

In asp.net web API i am using Action Filter Attribute that i override `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` to validate a token send from client in a header when adding that attribute over any controller i can intercept the request before passing it to functions in the controller till now every thing is working fine but that is not true if i add the same attribute over a Hub class as when i debug i can see that methods on the hub get excuted first then `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`. How to solve that problem.

```
 [OurAuthorization]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub 
    {
        private AccPlusEntities1 db = new AccPlusEntities1();

        public void TrnAddedNotfication(string GroupName)
        {
            Clients.OthersInGroup(GroupName).AddedNotfication();
        }

        public void TrnDeletedNotfication(string GroupName)
        {
            Clients.OthersInGroup(GroupName).DeletedNotfication();
        }

        public void JoinGroup(string AccName)
        {
            var x = BaseController.CurrentUser.AccId;
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, AccName);
        }

        public void LeaveGroup(string AccName)
        {
            Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, AccName);
        }

        public void Lock(int TrnId)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action Filter Attributes do not work with SignalR Hubs as you've discovered. Fortunately SignalR does provide it's own [AuthorizeAttribute](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization#authorizeattribute) which fulfills the same purpose.

As with `ActionFilterAttribute`s, you can subclass an SignalR's [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and override the [UserAuthorized method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.authorizeattribute.userauthorized(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Also you can override AuthorizeHubConnection method and get all information about request (for log events).